# Esc key press event for QListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, signals-slots, qlistview

I created a simple `QListView` added a `QStringListModel` that allow items to be added and their text edited. But I don't want to allow empty fields to be added and I partially achieved this by using the `dataChanged` signal from the model which is emitted if the list item loses focus without text inserted or the user presses the `Enter` key without adding text.

However if you press the `Esc` key, the field remains empty and no `dataChanged` signal is emitted. How can I get notified if the field was left empty without overloading the `QListView` class which would be tedious(I used the designer to create the form)?

Is there another signal that is emitted or method I can use to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [event filters](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) in your main GUI class:

```
void GUI::GUI()
{     
    ui->mListView->installEventFilter(this);
}
bool GUI::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->mListView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
           // special Esc handling here
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

It's simple to use your custom widgets in Qt Designer. Right click on the QListView and choose Promote to ... there add a new class and apply it to the widget.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Are you sure that the list view is the object that receives the key event? When user edits a list view item, there is a line edit widget that handles user input, so probably that editor handles key events as well?

Comment: Well, that could be true, I've never used QListView. But I don't think there's any other way to do it if this doesn't work... However, using custom widgets in Qt Designer is simple, I'll add it to my answer.